# all instances attach directly to the provider network

Tags: openstack

I'm deploying openstack - stein version with Ubuntu pro 18.04 LTS.

As of this [article](https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/environment-networking.html), I'm preparing the underlying networking infrastructure that binds openstack nodes : controller, compute, ...

I need to know what's the utility of provider network and what's the best approach to implement the provider network :

- connect all nodes directly to internet with public IP addresses ?
- place the nodes behind a NAT, even in provider network configuration, and have one public IP address and multiple private IP ?

Answer (score 1):

A provider network represents an external network to which the cloud is connected. Very often, a cloud has a single provider network, but it's no problem to have several. Without a provider network, you have no external connectivity.

It's not hard to find articles that explain the provider network concept, for example https://superuser.openstack.org/articles/tenant-networks-vs-provider-networks-in-the-private-cloud-context/.

What is the best approach depends on your need. For example:

- If it's OK that all instances share the same network, attach them to a provider network (or several provider networks).
- If you don't want projects to share their network, configure a cloud that allows *tenant networks*, i.e. roughly the NAT configuration you describe.
- It should also be possible to use VLANs for network separation, though my knowledge of that is sketchy.
- If projects need
  multi-tier networking topologies, you definitely need tenant
  networks.

By the way, even with NAT'ed tenant networks, you will need one external/public IP address per instance that you want to access from outside. These public IP addresses are named *floating IPs*.

Comment: Thanks for informations. I can't declare 2 NICs on controller node. As of this [article](http://https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/environment-networking-controller.html), when implementing the second NIC (eth1) as provider network interface, and keeping eth0 as mgmt interface. I loose connectivity when ssh-ing controller node again. I don't know why ...

Comment: I mean eth1 precedes over eth0, or something like this.

Comment: You can easily declare a second NIC, even if your controller is a physical machine. For example, create a VLAN interface, or one of the old `eth0:1` interfaces that were used to add an IP address.